# How to find the continuous sum of the indexed array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a matrix that takes the value of row and column by the user and prints the matrix value.

I have a situation where i get the values and store it in an array, for example:

lets have a matrix of dimension 1x4 where the user gives a input as `[1 2 3 4]`. I need to perform a calculation where I take 2 values inside the array perform addition, then add it with the next index value and so on until the length of the array is equal to the number of column value given by the user.
I have an update where I need to add the values this way `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as `(1+2)=3`, `(3+3=6)`, `(6+4=10)` and do this operation `(3+6+10 = 19)` this is my requirement actually, sorry for not mentioning this in the question

What I have so far:

```
# A basic code for matrix input from user 
import numpy as np
  
R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:")) 
C = int(input("Enter the number of columns:")) 
  
# Initialize matrix 
matrix = [] 
print("Enter the entries rowwise:") 
  
# For user input 
for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries 
    a =[] 
    for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries 
         a.append(int(input())) 
    matrix.append(a) 
    z = len(a)
    # print (z)
    for i in a:
        if (i == z):
            val = a[0] + a[1]
            print(val)
```

im new to coding so i have less idea about it please help me out, thank you in advance

Comment: I added the code. Check out my answer 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this should be what you were asking for :

```
    # A basic code for matrix input from user 
import numpy as np
  
def add_matrix_rox(row: list) -> float:
        r = row[0] + row[1]
        result = r
        for num in row[2:]:
            r += num
            result += r
        return result

R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:")) 
C = int(input("Enter the number of columns:")) 
  
# Initialize matrix 
matrix = [] 
print("Enter the entries rowwise:") 
  
# For user input 
for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries 
    a =[] 
    for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries 
         a.append(int(input())) 
    matrix.append(a)
    print(f'Matrix formed : {a}')
    print(f'Sum of the row : {add_matrix_rox(a)}')
```

I created a function 'add_matrix_row' that calculates the sum of the row the way you intended it

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the part of your code after second input with this. I updated the code.

```
matrix = [] 
print("Enter the entries rowwise:") 

# For user input 
for  i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries 
    a =[] 
    total_sum=0
    for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries 
         a.append(int(input())) 
    value= a[0:0+2]
    sums=sum(value)
    tsum+=sums
    for i in range(2,len(a)):
        sums+=a[i]
        tsum+=sums

    matrix.append(a) 
    print (f"Sum of {i+1} list is: ",tsum)
    total_sum+=tsum
    print(tsum)
    

print("Matrix formed: ",matrix)
print ("Total sum: ",total_sum)
print("Matrix formed: ",matrix)
print ("Total sum: ",total_sum)
```

Comment: i have an update where i need to add the values in such a way that [1, 2, 3, 4] as (1+2)=3, (3+3=6), (6+4=10) and do this operation (3+6+10 = 19) this is my requirement actually

Comment: There is just a minute change `tsum = 0` must be initialized in the code other than that its perfect!!, Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome, please accept the answer if this is what you need

Comment: Now I brought tsum inside the loop so it's gets reset every time

Answer (score 0):

the shortest answer I can come up with:

```
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [3, 4, 5, 6]
]

print(sum(map(sum, matrix)) == 28)
```

but if you just pack all entries to one list then

```
matrix = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,3, 4, 5, 6]

print(sum(matrix) == 28)
```

Comment: and what do you think sum function does?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understood what you meant but I came up with this :

```
# For user input 
for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries 
    a =[] 
    for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries 
         a.append(int(input())) 
    matrix.append(a) 

    print(sum(a)) # sums all the number in the array 'a'
```

Please tell me if this is what you were looking for

Comment: i have an update where i need to add the values in such a way that 
[1, 2, 3, 4] as (1+2)=3, (3+3=6), (6+4=10) and do this operation (3+6+10 = 19) this is my requirement actually, sorry for not mentioning this in the question

Comment: Do you need to do this for each row or the entire matrix ?

Comment: Yes, for each row of the matrix